# SQL Group by Not working.

Tags: mysql, sql, view, group-by

I have a very long list of SQL items being pulled from a view what I need to do is group by but only two of those items --

for example:

```
select distinct 
a.customer_no   ,
a.customer_prefix   ,
a.customer_lname    ,
a.customer_street1
... -- about 100 other rows 
a.inv_mail_dt,
a.pmt_due_dt,
a.pmt_rcvd_dt,
a.pmt_rcvd_amt,
a.perf_date,
a.perf_desc,
a.sub_line_item_price_type_desc ,
a.Price_type_desc,
sum(a.sli_due_amt),
sum(a.sli_paid_amt)
from VIEW a
Where a.customer_no = @customer_no
Group by 
a.customer_no,
a.order_no,
a.Price_type_desc
```

but I keep getting error messages that require me to add other columns/fields to the group by.  But those shouldn't be used to group by if they are unique then they should be separate if they are the same

Comment: Your group by is essentially invalid SQL. Every other DBMS would simply reject this query. For a longer explanation see e.g. here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But those [columns] shouldn't be used to group by if they are unique then they should be separate if they are the same

That's not how `GROUP BY` works. Each expression that you specify in your select must be one of two kinds:

- **A `GROUP BY` column** - i.e. a column from the `GROUP BY` list, or
- **An aggregate expression** - i.e. a function that selects `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `COUNT`, etc.

`GROUP BY` query will use the "group by" columns to split the results into "buckets", perform aggregations within each individual bucket, and return the results to you.

Since adding more columns to your `GROUP BY` list may result in creating more buckets than you need, another approach to solving this problem would be removing the unused columns altogether, running a `GROUP BY` and a "flat" queries separately, and joining the results either in your RDBMS or in the host environment:

```
select distinct 
    a.customer_no,
    a.order_no,
    a.Price_type_desc,
    a.customer_prefix,
    a.customer_lname,
    a.customer_street1
    ... -- about 100 other rows 
    a.inv_mail_dt,
    a.pmt_due_dt,
    a.pmt_rcvd_dt,
    a.pmt_rcvd_amt,
    a.perf_date,
    a.perf_desc,
    a.sub_line_item_price_type_desc,
    x.sum_sli_due_amt,
    x.sum_sli_paid_amt
from VIEW a
join (
    SELECT
    b.customer_no,
    b.order_no,
    b.Price_type_desc,
    sum(b.sli_due_amt) as sum_sli_due_amt,
    sum(b.sli_paid_amt) as sum_sli_paid_amt
    from VIEW b
    Group by 
    b.customer_no,
    b.order_no,
    b.Price_type_desc
   Where b.customer_no = @customer_no
) x ON a.customer_no=x.customer_no
   AND a.order_no=x.order_no
   AND a.Price_type_desc=x.Price_type_desc
Where a.customer_no = @customer_no
```

Comment: in the join - where the sum statements use "a" as the identifier (sum(a.sli_due_amt) as sum_sli_due_amt) for example. IT doesn't work - it only works once i change it to b. is that something different in logic?

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Ah yes, that's a typo - I copy/pasted both `sum` expressions from your SQL statement, and forgot to fix the alias. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I came across one problem -- sum(b.sli_due_amt) and    sum(b.sli_paid_amt) aren't coming back in my output set.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR They should be - that's what the items `x.sum_sli_due_amt` and `x.sum_sli_paid_amt` are supposed to return.